# Backbone sending parameters over AJAX to server

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

Hey,
I'm very new to backbone, and I've read a little bit of the documentation but I didn't find something appropriate. I would like to use backbone to send some data to the server using AJAX communication. Does backbone have some kind of shortcut to do this? For now my simple example consist of a HTML page with an input for username and one for the password. On clicking the button I fire this function:

```
    //handling the button event on the login form
    function loginPressed(){
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        loginModel.username = username;
        loginModel.password = password;


    }
```

The login model is just a model I've created with backbone:

```
//creating a backbone model to handle login
var loginModel = new Backbone.Model({
        username: "",
        password: "", 
    });
```

Do you think I can do AJAX request to my server with this?

Thanks,
Masiar

P.S. My serverside is node.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your model is not defined properly:

```
var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/your/login/url"
});
...

function loginPressed(){
  var login = new LoginModel
  login.save({
    username: document.getElementById("username").value,
    password: document.getElementById("password").value
  },{
    /*any other jquery ajax options including callbacks*/
  });
}
```

There are some reasons you should not do login with ajax calls but you'll learn them soon enough :)

Comment: You are right about the AJAX calls with logins, it's just that I wanted to integrate Backbone with Nodejs. Anyhow thanks, that's why I couldn't pass properly variables! :)